# lstlisting environment as item in description

Tags: listings, vertical-alignment, description

I would like to show some listings inside a `description` environment like this:

```
\usepackage{listings}   % fancy code listings
\usepackage{caption}    % fancy chapters for fancy code listings
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{singlelinecheck=false, margin=0pt, font={sf,sl,footnotesize}}

\lstset{%
  language=[ISO]C++,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
  frame=lines,
  keywordstyle=\color{blue}\textbf,
  commentstyle=\color[rgb]{0.0,0.4,0.0}\scriptsize,
  extendedchars=true,         
  breaklines=true             
}

\begin{description}
\item[Example:]
  \begin{lstlisting}[caption=Do not do this]
    /* increment a by one */
    a = a + 1
  \end{lstlisting}
\end{description}
```

But for some reason the caption *'Do not do this'* is always visible above the `\item` entry *'Example:'*. This problem however vanishes if I write something between `\item` and the `lstlisting` environment like this:

```
\begin{description}
\item[Example:] Bad code example
  \begin{lstlisting}[caption=Do not do this]
    /* increment a by one */
    a = a + 1
  \end{lstlisting}
\end{description}
```

I would like to get this to work without the extra text, *'Bad code example'* in this case.

I tried to use `\vspace{}` and `\phantom{text}` instead of extra text, but both seem to be ignored.

Could someone please help me out?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 7):

Adding a `\leavevmode` helps here:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}   % fancy code listings
\usepackage{caption}    % fancy chapters for fancy code listings
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{singlelinecheck=false, margin=0pt, font={sf,sl,footnotesize}}

\lstset{%
  language=[ISO]C++,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
  frame=lines,
  keywordstyle=\color{blue}\textbf,
  commentstyle=\color[rgb]{0.0,0.4,0.0}\scriptsize,
  extendedchars=true,         
  breaklines=true             
}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
\item[Example:]\leavevmode
  \begin{lstlisting}[caption=Do not do this]
    /* increment a by one */
    a = a + 1
  \end{lstlisting}
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot. That's exactly what I wanted to have ;-)

Comment: @Foka [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.