# Item numbers with listings

Tags: listings, enumerate

The following MWE

```
\documentclass{paper}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item
    \begin{lstlisting}
Hello, world
    \end{lstlisting}
    \item
    \begin{lstlisting}
Hello, world
    \end{lstlisting}
    \item
    \begin{lstlisting}
Hello, world
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

has the item numbers end up in the wrong position:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong with my `item`s? Is this a bug with listings?

Comment: Why do you use the paper class?

Comment: @TeXnician Is there something wrong with it? I like the way it looks more than `article`. In any case, the same behaviour happens with `article`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding a `\leavevmode` after each `lstlisting` environment solves the issue ([credits](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/186383/103046)). I used `etoolbox` with `\AfterEndEnvironment` to have it added automatically:

```
\documentclass{paper}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AfterEndEnvironment{lstlisting}{\leavevmode}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item
    \begin{lstlisting}
Hello, world
    \end{lstlisting}
    \item
    \begin{lstlisting}
Hello, world
    \end{lstlisting}
    \item
    \begin{lstlisting}
Hello, world
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show a small piece of code as items, you can do it with inline listings, using `\lstMakeShortInline`. You don't need `\leavevmode` in this case.

The following code generates a small piece of code listed as items:

```
\documentclass{paper}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\lstMakeShortInline[]|

With inline listings:

\begin{enumerate}
    \item |Hello, world|
    \item |Hello, world|
    \item |Hello, world|
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

`\lstMakeShortInline[]|` defines the vertical bar `|` as a character for inline listings. The code then has `|Hello, world|` in the enumerated list.
[image]

Comment: It's a minimal example. In the real document I have longer code snippets, and I want syntax highlighting there. So I really need `listings`.

Comment: The procedure above produces the enumerated items. What do you want to do?

Comment: Replace "Hello world" with a few lines of code, for instance [this source](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jhermsmeier/2269511/raw/e424bc10be6ce480bdae3751471ea48582ffc1f0/qrsqrt.js). I want this code typeset exactly like `listings` would do (fixed-width, with syntax highlighting, optional line numbering, etc.). And, of course, I want the item numbers 2 and 3 not to overlap. Is it clearer now?

Comment: I revised the answer to reflect the question more precisely.